# Auto functions in c++

Tags: c++

I'm not so familiar with C++. Can someone please inform me what this lines does (in detail):

```
auto add_element = [&rows,&cols,&values](size_t row, size_t col, double value)
{
    rows.push_back(int(row));
    cols.push_back(int(col));
    values.push_back(value);
};
```

Rows, cols, values are obvious vectors.

Is this the same as void add_element(vector & rows, size_t row, .....)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That defines and stores a lambda. Read [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) on more details or google up on C++11 and lambda.

> One of the most exciting features of C++11 is ability to create lambda functions (sometimes referred to as closures). What does this mean? A lambda function is a function that you can write inline in your source code (usually to pass in to another function, similar to the idea of a [functor](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html) or [function pointer](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html)). With lambda, creating quick functions has become much easier, and this means that not only can you start using lambda when you'd previously have needed to write a separate named function, but you can start writing more code that relies on the ability to create quick-and-easy functions. In this article, I'll first explain why lambda is great--with some examples--and then I'll walk through all of the details of what you can do with lambda...